# I'm trying to encode a number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Pulling a prank on a friend who brags is really good at math.  Need an complex equation where the answer will work out to 1346 in some context.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At a social level, if you're not better at math than this person and you try to trick them, I have a feeling it won't work out so well no matter what you do. Even if you manage to fool them or show them something they don't understand or can't figure out, you still don't have the knowledge they do. Being better at math doesn't make them better than others, even if they want to tell themselves it does.

Comment: Nowadays everybody is an expert in math, thanks to Wolfram Alpha ))

Answer (score 9):

Take a random function with no real roots, say $5^x((x+1)^2+1)$. Then multiply with $x-1346$. Using this example, we get:

Find all real numbers such that:

$$5^xx^3 -1344 \cdot 5^xx^2-2690 \cdot 5^x x-2692 \cdot 5^x=0$$

Of course, one cold take a much harder starting equation, for example $2^{2^x}\log(x+1)+(x+1)^4+4546$, as long as it has no roots.

Comment: Now that's pretty cool.

Comment: It's cool **and** diabolical!

Comment: Nice, but the $5^x$ does almost nothing, so this 'only' a polynomial of degree $3$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha solves this really quickly.

Comment: Trivial. 5^x is instantly removed, then you only have a simple third degree equation to sovle, which is pretty simple.

Comment: Then use a different starting equation, like $5^xx^5-2x^3+5x+4$, I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Should integration be accepted too (I just noticed the ENT tag...) try the neat $\,a=13\,$ in :
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^8-3a}{\cosh(x\frac{\pi}2)}\,dx$$

Concerning number theory let's observe ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=kQRPkTkk_VIC)) :

- $1346=2\cdot(672+1)\quad$ where $\;N:=672=2^5\cdot 3\cdot 7\;$ is the second [triperfect number](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-42-165/S0025-5718-1984-0725999-4/S0025-5718-1984-0725999-4.pdf) (i.e. the sum of the positive divisors of $N$ is equal to $3N$).
- the smallest triplet $\;(n+29,n+30,n+31)\;$ of positive integers all divisible by a cube different of $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Give the prime factorization of $1743388617272249143997555461487119439669521095365209$.

Comment: Are you saying the prime factorization of your number is 1346?  Isn't the OP asking for a question where the answer is 1346?

Comment: It's $13^{46}$. :-)

Answer (score 3):

$n=1346$ is the $270$th integer solution of:
$$ \phi(\phi(\phi(n)))=2^6$$
with $\phi$ being the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), and also the number we get by swapping the last two digits of the $15$th [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number). Moreover, $1346$ is a semiprime [sandwiched between semiprimes](https://oeis.org/A086005) and $1346$ is the number of distinct products of the form $ijk$ for $1\leq i<j<k\leq 27$, or:
$$ 1346 = \sum_{k=7^2}^{8^2-1}\sigma(k) $$
where $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, but if you haven't been introduced to geometric series, the following might appear rather strange:

$$1346 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1345}{1346}\right)^n$$

Comment: Perhaps, but wouldn't the $1346$ be obvious just from looking at it?

Comment: maybe, but why not 1345? or any other number? I get what you're saying: the number's there. What I'm saying is: depending on the skill level, that the sum is *also* equal 1346 may seem magical - for lack of a better adjective.

Comment: Oh no, I agree with that part, certainly.  My only concern is that the OP might want even the notion of the number to remain hidden until it is obtained as the answer.

Comment: I agree. I was initially not going to post this answer for that reason. However, OP was vague and has remained silent on that aspect, so I figured I'd just toss one more on the pile :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(0)&=6\\
f'(1)&=13\\
f''(2)&=18\\
f'''(3)&=6\\
f^{(n)}(n)&=0\quad\text{for }n>3\\
f(10)&=\boxed?
\end{align}
Not sure how hard this is, though.

Comment: There's not a unique solution, $f(10)$ can be anything. We can define some piecewise function that satisfies the first 4 requirements, and then for $x>3$ we can let $f(x)=k$ for any constant $k$, which satisfies the fifth requirement.

Comment: @PeterOlson Ah, true… Let's say $f$ is analytic (or perhaps let's say it's a polynomial). Does that work?